# How to select multiple dates from single date slicer in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to select multiple dates from single Date slicer to filter data based on Series_Name slicer.
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks.

This is the report for reference

[image: 1]

Unable to select multiple dates from date picker in PowerBI.
Tried using multiple date slicers but also did not worked.
I am new to PowerBI and googled things about it but cant do.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Date slicer allows you to pick start and end dates for a desired date range. Once you pick the dates, the slicer provides multiple dates in the selected range. What is the issue?

Comment: I do not want a range of dates from start and end dates instead i want to select multiple dates from a single date picker only. Multi date selection from a single date picker.

Comment: If you want to select specific dates, then change the type of the slicer. The one you currently use will always provide a range of dates.

Comment: If there are dates for suppose 6 months in the data, then it would be different for user to choose from other types. That is why i want to choose date picker to select multiple dates. It would be easy. Thanks for suggestion.